# Google Analytics Destination Goal

Tags: google, google-analytics, analytics

Is it possible to track how long does it take for a user to reach their goal via Destination Goal in Google Analytics?

Something similar to checkout process, google starts tracking from when the item is added to the basket all the way (2-3 steps) to checkout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not possible as a standard analytics setup, but you can use a [PHP / javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244176/countdown-timer) timer (or whatever language you use). start the timer when the process starts and end it on the thank you page.

Once you have the time put it inside an event and send to analytics. You can send the time together with product category etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can track it server-side in the user's session or client-side (in-browser) with localStorage. If you do it locally, when they start record:

```
window.localStorage.startAction = Date.now();
```

When they finish, you can get the number of seconds using:

```
var secondsToComplete = ( Date.now() - window.localStorage.startAction ) / 1000;
gaq.push(SOMETHING, secondsToComplete;)
```

I'd wrap both lines inside of a

```
if (window.localStorage) {
}
```

in case the user is on an older browser that doesn't support localStorage